# What does this C error about structures mean?

Tags: c, initialization, structure

Could someone please help me understand this error in C for structures?
This is my code:

```
struct Orientation
{
    char facing;
    char sensor;
    char mazeDir;
}; 

struct Orientation O[16];
O[0] = {'N', 'F', 'N'};
O[1] = {'N', 'B', 'S'};
O[2] = {'N', 'R', 'E'};
O[3] = {'N', 'L', 'W'};
O[4] = {'S', 'F', 'S'};
O[5] = {'S', 'B', 'N'};
O[6] = {'S', 'R', 'W'};
O[7] = {'S', 'L', 'E'};
O[8] = {'E', 'F', 'E'};
O[9] = {'E', 'B', 'W'};
O[10] = {'E', 'R', 'S'};
O[11] = {'E', 'L', 'N'};
O[12] = {'W', 'F', 'W'};
O[13] = {'W', 'B', 'E'};
O[14] = {'W', 'R', 'N'};
O[15] = {'W', 'L', 'S'};
```

and I get these errors regarding O[13], O[14] and O[15]

```
..\RMNCODE.C(282): error C231: 'O': redefinition
..\RMNCODE.C(283): error C279: 'O': multiple initialization
..\RMNCODE.C(283): error C231: 'O': redefinition
..\RMNCODE.C(284): error C279: 'O': multiple initialization
..\RMNCODE.C(284): error C231: 'O': redefinition
```

Answer (score 8):

Initialize the array like this instead:

```
struct Orientation O[16] = {
    {'N', 'F', 'N'},
    {'N', 'B', 'S'},
    {'N', 'R', 'E'},
    {'N', 'L', 'W'},
    {'S', 'F', 'S'},
    {'S', 'B', 'N'},
    {'S', 'R', 'W'},
    {'S', 'L', 'E'},
    {'E', 'F', 'E'},
    {'E', 'B', 'W'},
    {'E', 'R', 'S'},
    {'E', 'L', 'N'},
    {'W', 'F', 'W'},
    {'W', 'B', 'E'},
    {'W', 'R', 'N'},
    {'W', 'L', 'S'}
};
```

Cheers !

Comment: Can you explain why the O[13] and subsequent lines cause errors?

Comment: These errors are the same for all lines. Not just for 13, 14 and 15.

Comment: I have never seen so many practically identical answers in one question! :)

Comment: Lol, you had to be fast to grab this reputation. I even managed to compile and test. How about that? ;)

Comment: @Magnus, lucky lucky ... I was still in vim when the orange-bar-of-death appeared.

Comment: "orange-bar-of-death" hehehe :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to initialize O, you need to do it all at once as part of the declaration:

```
struct Orientation O[16] = {
  { 'N', 'F', 'N' },
  { 'N', 'B', 'S'),
  ...
```

};

You can't do this:

```
O[0] = {'N', 'F', 'N'};
```

because C doesn't support struct literals in a statement, only as part of an initializer list.

Comment: I think this will be ok： O[0] = (char []){'N','F','N'}; according to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals

Comment: @AllanRuin: Yes, but that's a GCC extension. Not standard C.

Answer (score 3):

Either you have to initialize `O` with a single initializer, or you can assign to its members individually in an initialization function. You can't use assignment expressions outside of a function as you have done.

e.g.

```
struct Orientation O[16] = { {'N', 'F', 'N'}, {'N', 'B', 'S'} /* , ... */ };
```

or

```
void InitializeO(void)
{
    O[0].facing = 'N';
    O[0].sensor = 'F';
    O[0].mazeDir = 'N';

    O[1].facing = 'N';
    O[1].sensor = 'B';
    O[1].mazeDir = 'S';

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the assignment by an initialization.

```
struct Orientation { char facing; char sensor; char mazeDir; };

struct Orientation O[16] = 
{{'N', 'F', 'N'},
{'N', 'B', 'S'}, 
{'N', 'R', 'E'}, 
{'N', 'L', 'W'}, 
{'S', 'F', 'S'}, 
{'S', 'B', 'N'}, 
{'S', 'R', 'W'}, 
{'S', 'L', 'E'}, 
{'E', 'F', 'E'}, 
{'E', 'B', 'W'}, 
{'E', 'R', 'S'}, 
{'E', 'L', 'N'}, 
{'W', 'F', 'W'}, 
{'W', 'B', 'E'}, 
{'W', 'R', 'N'}, 
{'W', 'L', 'S'}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a struct like you're doing.  You need to do it explicitly:

```
O[0].facing = 'N';
O[0].sensor = 'F';
O[0].mazeDir = 'N';

O[1].facing = 'N';
O[1].sensor = 'B';
O[1].mazeDir = 'S';

//etc...
```

Or else you can initialize the struct like Magnus suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
struct Orientation O[16] = {
    { 'W','L','S'},
    { 'W', 'R', 'N'},
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not direct answer to your question, you can solve the problem by following syntax:

```
struct Orientation O[16] = {
  {'N', 'F', 'N' },
  {'N', 'B', 'S'},
  {'N', 'R', 'E'},
  {'N', 'L', 'W'},
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C89 doesn't have literals for structures. It does have initialization lists, which look as if they are literals, but really aren't.

This means that you can only do the "initializing assignment" once, where the variable is defined:

```
struct Orientation O[16] = {
  {'N', 'F', 'N'},
  ...
};
```

In C99, this has changed, see the link in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Compound literals is what you are looking for if you want to assign the values at a later time, the syntax you want is

```
struct Orientation O[16];
O[0] = (struct Orientation){'N', 'F', 'N'};
O[1] = (struct Orientation){'N', 'B', 'S'};
O[2] = (struct Orientation){'N', 'R', 'E'};
O[3] = (struct Orientation){'N', 'L', 'W'};
O[4] = (struct Orientation){'S', 'F', 'S'};
O[5] = (struct Orientation){'S', 'B', 'N'};
O[6] = (struct Orientation){'S', 'R', 'W'};
O[7] = (struct Orientation){'S', 'L', 'E'};
O[8] = (struct Orientation){'E', 'F', 'E'};
O[9] = (struct Orientation){'E', 'B', 'W'};
O[10] = (struct Orientation){'E', 'R', 'S'};
O[11] = (struct Orientation){'E', 'L', 'N'};
O[12] = (struct Orientation){'W', 'F', 'W'};
O[13] = (struct Orientation){'W', 'B', 'E'};
O[14] = (struct Orientation){'W', 'R', 'N'};
O[15] = (struct Orientation){'W', 'L', 'S'};
```

The advantage is that it can be done everywhere within the function and not only during initialization time.

Although as everyone else suggested, you can just rewrite it as:

```
struct Orientation O[16] = 
{
    {'N', 'F', 'N'},
    {'N', 'B', 'S'}, 
    {'N', 'R', 'E'},
    ...
};
```

Or even

```
struct Orientation O[16] =
{
    [0] = {'N', 'F', 'N'},
    [1] = {'N', 'B', 'S'},
    [2] = {'N', 'R', 'E'},
    [3] = {'N', 'L', 'W'},
    ...
};
```

If you just want to assign the values during initialization time.

Comment: You can only use these assignments inside a function body (in particular, you cannot use them "everywhere", and certainly not where the OP was using them, which is outside a function, right next to the type declaration).

Comment: @jogojapan How do you know the OP is not using them inside a function body? The question lacks any indication of that. "anywhere" where an assignment can take place. The way I saw it is he is trying to assign a value to one of O's indexes at a later time.

Comment: I know that the OP is using the code outside a function body because otherwise the error message would be about assigning `{...}` directly to a variable being illegal. But the error message is about multiple definitions.